# Get user photo from Active directory not working at server

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, dns, active-directory

I am developing an intranent website that take the user name direct from windows authentication then get more data from active directory such as user image and user email and so on at the folowing function

```
public Boolean userAuth()
{
    String myUser = Environment.UserName; 
    if (myUser == null)
    {
        return false; 
    }


    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
    de.Path = "LDAP://mydomain.com";
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();
    search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + myUser + ")";
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
    search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" +myUser + "))";
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("thumbnailPhoto");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Company");
    SearchResult user;
    user = search.FindOne();
    String userName;
    userName = Convert.ToString(user.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]);
    byte[] bb = (byte[])user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0];
    string imgString = Convert.ToBase64String(bb);
    Session["UserPhoto"] = String.Format("<img width='40' src=\"data:image/Bmp;base64,{0}\">", imgString);
    result = search.FindOne();
    if (null == result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My pc is connected to the domain when i run the site in my local pc it works fine but when i put it in company application server
the `Environment.UserName` will not return the username  so i use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Replace("mydomain","")` but it will return that *user* null

I want to get user photo from AD to use it in the intranet site.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at iis application pool advance settings set process module identity to a user who is already in the domain